# Is there any way easy way to convert my existing react.js project to typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an existing project with react.js and now want to convert it to typescript. I followed an article on converting to typescript but I am facing many bugs and issues right. Is there any easy way for this conversion? Also, can I have both javascript files and typescript files in react project without facing any errors?

Comment: Can you share some of the specific error messages you're seeing? Also, are you using any framework for this project (like create react app or anything)?

Answer (score 1):

Your question would benefit from having more specifics. For example:

- What article did you read? Include a link
- What do you mean by "easy"? That's a subjective term; generally good questions will focus on a specific issue that can be reproduced by another
- What are the bugs and issues that you're encountering? This is perhaps the most important context that's missing in your question

With that aside, here are some general pointers that may be helpful.

Converting a React project over to TS involves some work, but it doesn't have to be done all at once. Since JS compiles to TS, you can build out the infrastructure to *support* Typescript first, and then refactor bit by bit.

How familiar are you with Typescript? There's a relatively steep learning curve and some of your errors may be due to this reason.

One tip I can offer, without seeing your code, is to let Typescript work its magic of type inference when possible; this can save you the trouble of stumbling into thickets that you could just as easily bypass.

Yes, you can have JS and TS files coexisting in a React project, as long as the project supports TS. As @Barryman9000 pointed out, adding TS support depends on your specific framework; if you're on a CRA project then you may want to view the [documentation on adding typescript](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/).

Comment: Idem what Chris Perry & @Barryman9000 said about your question. I'd be happy to help if you provide some more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is a **superscript** of JavaScript (sort of). It is meant for developers to add extra information to the code to be able to certain things (like type checking) during compile time in the IDE instead of during run time.

Since typescript is **transpiled** to JS, you can use any JavaScript in a typescript file (although your framework and/or linter might not like it that you are ignoring certain imposed rules) or even in ".js" files, yes. This would however, defeat the purpose of using typescript.

To answer your question, there isn't really an 'easy' way like a translator, if that is what you mean. It is impossible to infer all the information you can add to your JS (by using typescript) from the context.

Your IDE might be able to help with some of your issues. The issues you will encounter also depend on the framework you are using, and the imposed rules. You will have to to look at them on a case by case basis.

To give the example for **type checking**:
When your JS-code takes in foreign objects it knows nothing about them until it gets one. You could tell the compiler it is of type **any** in your typescript, but this way there is no type checking because the compiler will not know anyhting about the foreign object either. In typescript you would define what the object looks like with a model and let the compiler know the incoming object is of that type. No algorithm would ever be able to define what this object would look like, just by going through your existing JS code since itself only 'finds out' during runtime.

Often your IDE won't even complain about these things and it is totally up to you to implement everything to have type checking. If you don't however, you might as well just not use typescript. So just solving the issues your IDE is pointing out isn't even the whole story.

If your project is small and something only you are working on, it might even be a valid choice to not have the overhead.

For us to help you out we would have to know more about the issues you are facing (IDE messages, error logs, ...).